# Java Swing Tree with Streaming Updates

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, tree

I have a Swing tree that is changing as a result of a background thread that receives updates to the tree, in a streaming fashion. Updates can come quite fast and they can be complex. And they can come fast enough that previous updates have not yet been rendered. I would like the tree displayed in the GUI to be visually updated, as fast as practical, as the tree model updates are applied.

Currently I have code abstractly as below:

```
public void ReceiveStreamDocument(final Document d) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            ComplexChangeToTree(d);
            TreeReload();
        }
    });
}
```

Now the complex change is time consuming, what I would like is:

```
public void ReceiveStreamDocument(final Document d) {
    ComplexChangeToTree(d);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            TreeReload();
        }
    });
}
```

However the problem appears to be that modifications to the tree structure are now outside of the swing thread and when the tree is actually re-rendered there can be exceptions thrown. It does not seem to help to have something like this:

```
public void ReceiveStreamDocument(final Document d) {
    synchronized(root){
        ComplexChangeToTree(d);
    }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            synchronized(root){
               TreeReload();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The TreeReload() is not actually updating the display, but rather just signaling that the display should be updated. I believe I need to override a painting operation somewhere and synchronize root on that, but I'm not sure where, or how, or indeed what is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is doing as much as possible in the background and firing as few tree model events as possible to the listening tree. Using [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), collect updates in your implementation of `doInBackground()`, where you can also do any parsing and rearranging that doesn't fire events from your [`TreeModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data). Invoke `publish()` for results as they become available. A `List` of accumulated results will be coalesced and passed to your implementation of `process()` on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) at a sustainable [rate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11838349/230513), where you have another opportunity to optimize firing update events. A related question is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26524209/230513).

Comment: Thanks for that. I had a read about `SwingWorker`. As far as I understand the "heavy" work is meant to be done in the `doInBackground()` implementation. However the work involves modifying my tree (`DefaultMutableTreeNode`s), and my tree model (`DefaultTreeModel`) is dependent on my tree, and my `JTree` is dependent on my model. When modifying the tree (which doesn't fire any events in itself correct?), how does use of `SwingWorker` guarantee that there is no GUI updates that will occur concurrently? I'm assuming the `process()` implementation would simply call the tree reload.

Comment: Yes, `process()` is called on the event dispatch thread; `DefaultTreeModel` fires tree model events for you on `reload()`, etc.; you may have to [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to see where to optimize.